# Add custom field type to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, guice

Is it possible to add a custom field type to ElasticSearch? I would like to add a type similar to "geo_point" but I'm note sure what kind of plugin / module I need to create for this. Are there any tutorials or examples that cover this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more why you need a similar type for that?

Comment: The type that I would like to use is not similar with respect to functionality but similar in the way it is handled by ElasticSearch. I would like to introduce a "timed segment" type (i.e. a term with a start and end time). It would look something like this: `{ "term" : "..", "start" : 123456, "end" 234567 }`

Comment: The current implementation of the `IndexFieldDataService` creates the type mappings:
`buildersByType = MapBuilder.<String, IndexFieldData.Builder>newMapBuilder()
                .put("string", new PagedBytesIndexFieldData.Builder()) ...`
Is it possible to add more types using injection? Replacing the `IndexFieldDataService` seems not possible.

Comment: javanna gives you the answer of how to add custom field type, but I would like to understand your need of doing that. Are you trying to add a timed segment for something like expiration date? I'm saying this because you might not need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely possible to add a custom field type to elasticsearch through a plugin. That's exactly what the [Mapper attachments plugin](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments) does to make available the custom attachment type. Have a look at the code, it's on [github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments).

Comment: Thank you for this pointer. Is it possible to supply an array of objects in this way? Each element in the array should result in a term / token that will be indexed. For these terms I would like to set the start and end offset attributes.

Comment: It sounds like it's possible, but I am wondering too why you would need this. Cheers!